# Naming convention for Properties in Class

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, wsdl

I am accessing a remote service which returns data in an XML format with NameSpace etc. When I got the WSDL, which also included the response definitions, I found that I dont like the Property Names.

For example, how can I keep the original Property Name?

```vb
Partial Public Class ADDR_VAL_RESP
    Inherits LSR_INQUIRY_RESP_Type

    Private rESP_STATUS_GRPField() As RESP_STATUS_GRP

    Private itemField As Object

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RESP_STATUS_GRP")>
    Public Property RESP_STATUS_GRP() As RESP_STATUS_GRP()
        Get
            Return Me.rESP_STATUS_GRPField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.rESP_STATUS_GRPField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

In the above case it takes the RESP_STATUS_GRP and returns it as `rESP_STATUS_GRPField` but I would rather keep the original name as it is much cleaner.

Also how can I remove all properties which are null before returning them, as some of the classes might have 20 + properties but only 4 or so have values? Not only is it cleaner, but also saves traffic as return will be smaller.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Is this your class? You can make the property an auto-property since you don't have any special access modifiers. `Public Property RESP_STATUS_GRP() As RESP_STATUS_GRP()` and get rid of the backing field. Can you include some xml in your question?

Comment: Anyway, you can serialize any element into any property by changing the Element text attribute in `<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RESP_STATUS_GRP")>`. Awaiting more info...

Answer (score 0):

Keep the names from the remote system.  There are ways to use different names but you will set up a maintenance problem by modifying the WSDL generated C# classes.

At best, create a class which has a data object of type returned by the WSDL service and use your own naming scheme.

Two cases:

1. What if the WSDL service changes a name which is used throughout your application?
2. What if the WSDL data comes in a completely different format?   Seen this when our accounting system used WSDL and a corporate merger caused us to integrate with another accounting system from the acquired company.  The acquired company's accounting system had a different data format.
   We ended up converting the acquired company's data format to the one used by the other account system.

Short answer: Insulate your system from names, structures and failures in external systems.